# Inno Setup: Hide Preparing to Install page

Tags: inno-setup

When I try to install my app over already installed instance, Inno Setup installer shows "Preparing to Install" page, which in my case is blank as I hide most of standard labels. Is it possible to hide manually this page?

```pascal
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  case CurPageID of wpPreparing
    WizardForm.PreparingPage.Visible := False;// doesn't work. 
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You first need to tell us why does the page even display? What's its content when you do not hide it? What do you want to display instead?

Comment: At the first instalation Preparing page doesn't display, so I guess that at  overinstalation  installer removes old files.If I don't hide controls it shoes "Preparing to install" message. All I want is not to show this page at all.

Comment: Why do you want to hide it?

Comment: it's required by the our customer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correct, the installer does not stop on the "Preparing to Install" page, right?

You just want to avoid that momentary display of the page just before the actual installation starts, right?

You cannot. There's no way. You can of course modify the page to look differently, if needed, but you cannot skip it.

Comment: That's correct. Thanks for reply Martin, really appreciate your help.